# torch.hub.load() raises HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found when loading model

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, fairseq, torchhub

I had this simple piece of code found on the [fairseq](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/main/examples/bart/README.md#filling-masks) GitHub repository which basically loads the `bart.base` PyTorch model from `torch.hub`:

```py
bart = torch.hub.load('pytorch/fairseq', 'bart.base')
```

This code was working perfectly around two weeks ago, now it raises the following error despite the fact that I didn't change anything:

```
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-68181b5f094c> in <module>()
      1 # torch.cuda.empty_cache()
----> 2 bart = torch.hub.load('pytorch/fairseq', 'bart.base') #takes around two minutes
      3 # bart.cuda()  # use GPU
...
...
/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Also, I found out that this happens with other models on `fairseq`. All the following models raise the same error:

```
>>> torch.hub.load('pytorch/fairseq', 'transformer.wmt16.en-de')
# ERROR!

>>> torch.hub.load('pytorch/fairseq', 'camembert')
# ERROR!
```

So, there must be something in common among all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the `fairseq` folks decided to change the default branch of their GitHub repository from `master` to `main` exactly 7 days ago. (check this [commit](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/commit/f6abcc2a67328bee8b15c596bb626ce2d720aae6)).

So, adding the `main` branch to the repo info will fix the problem:

```
bart = torch.hub.load('pytorch/fairseq:main', 'bart.base') #<--- added :main
```

And that's because in `torch.hub.load()` function the default branch name is `master`. So actually, you were calling `pytorch/fairseq:master` which doesn't exist anymore.

And all other models are working now:

```
torch.hub.load('pytorch/fairseq:main', 'transformer.wmt16.en-de')
# WORKS!

>>> torch.hub.load('pytorch/fairseq:main', 'camembert')
# WORKS!
```